# In which way "verb+-doing" can be used to mean "something has been done"

Tags: present-tense, present-participles

I can't remember it clearly. somewhat "-ing" form as present participle can represent an event that is happening (e.g., Being given a chance, she immediately jumped at it)(as adverbial clause of time); or has been done（?); or will happen（I'm leaving tomorrow), of cause in different context. In which way "verb+-doing" can be used to mean "something has been done" or should it be used with specific verbs?

Answer (score 1):

You're asking in what way present tense verbs can be used to show something has been done.

You can say "I am *digging* the garden", which is a present-tense form of the verb *to dig*. When you have finished you could either say "I dug the garden today" (which is the past tense of the verb), *or* "*I have been digging the garden today*".

Also, a present-tense verb can be used as a *noun* for the job that it relates to. A good example of this is *ironing*.

The *action* of pressing clothes with a flat iron is the verb *to iron*, so while you were doing it in the present tense you would say "I am ironing". However, the job, or task, of doing it is called "ironing" (a noun) and, certainly in British English, the workload - a pile of unironed clothes - can also be named "ironing".

So if you said, "I have finished the ironing" you are speaking about a job that has *finished*. Although you are using an "-ing" form of a verb, it is really being used a *noun*.

---

So, you can use a present tense verb - an "-ing" word - in the past tense by saying "I have been digging/ironing/running", and you can also use some verbs in this form as nouns.

Comment: notice sb.do sth. (thing has done); notice sb.doing sth. (thing is happening); notice sth.done （thing has been done）. maybe I have remembered it wrongly. notice sb. do sth represent the thing has done.

Comment: It is adj to do something vs. it is adj doing something: to do here represent a specific thing while doing here represent repeating behavior. is that right. may be i have mixed this usage of gerund with the usage of present participle.